# How to join non-existent rows without coalesce?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table with data change history, that looks like:

```
+--------+----------+---------------+
| id     | key      | value         |
+--------+----------+---------------+
| UUID-1 | editedBy | moderator     |
+--------+----------+---------------+
| UUID-1 | comments | deleted...    |
+--------+----------+---------------+
| UUID-2 | editedBy | low_moderator |
+--------+----------+---------------+
| UUID-2 | comments | deleted...    |
+--------+----------+---------------+
| UUID-3 | editedBy | admin         |
+--------+----------+---------------+
| UUID-4 | editedBy | admin2        |
+--------+----------+---------------+
```

Now I want to select key-value with editor and key-value with `comments`(that not matches with `deleted...`), so I've done it this way.

```
with table1 as 
(
   SELECT
      sch.rid,
      sch.rkey,
      sch.rvalue,
      coalesce( (
      SELECT
         rvalue 
      FROM
         test sch2 
      WHERE
         sch.rid = sch2.rid 
         AND sch2.rkey = 'comments' ), ' ' ) AS comments 
      FROM
         test sch 
      WHERE
         rkey = 'editedBy'
)
SELECT
   * 
FROM
   table1 t1 
WHERE
   t1.comments != 'deleted...'
```

and I've got desired output

```
+--------+----------+--------+----------+
| id     | key      | value  | comments |
+--------+----------+--------+----------+
| UUID-3 | editedBy | admin  |          |
+--------+----------+--------+----------+
| UUID-4 | editedBy | admin2 |          |
+--------+----------+--------+----------+
```

But, it seems to me, that my script is too complicated and there are ways to do it better, but I can't find them alone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` :

```
SELECT * 
  FROM test t 
 WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 0
                      FROM test
                     WHERE rkey = 'comments' 
                       AND rvalue = 'deleted...'
                       AND rid = t.rid );
```

or alternatively you can use such a method containing analytic function :

```
WITH t AS
(
SELECT t.*, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN rkey = 'comments' AND rvalue='deleted...' 
                THEN 1 
                ELSE 0 
                END) OVER (PARTITION BY rid) AS cnt
  FROM test t 
)
SELECT rid, rkey, rvalue
  FROM t
 WHERE cnt = 0;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=adbd7943cf360746dc7e99c5dade2228)</kbd>

Comment: Instead of `SELECT 0...`, I like to select a string that describes the row I'm checking for.  E.g., `SELECT 'comment indicating ID is deleted'...`.

Answer (score 0):

Window functions:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             MAX(comments) OVER (PARTITION BY rid) as comments
      FROM test t
     ) t 
WHERE t1.comments <> 'deleted...'
```

Comment: can't realize how it can work. anyway, ORA-00904: "COMMENTS": invalid identifier.
my fiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c7a87/3/0

Answer (score 0):

You description suggest, that you have only two keys `comments` and `editedBy` in rows with the same UUID and that the former is optional.

Therefore simple use an `OUTER JOIN` and filter the row you do not want to see (rows with comment)

```
select 
  ed.rid, ed.rkey, ed.rvalue
from table1 ed
left outer join table1 del
on ed.RID = del.RID and del.rkey = 'comments'
where ed.rkey = 'editedBy'
and del.rkey is NULL /* no comment */
```